# jQuery function to open link in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popupwindow

I'm trying to find a plugin or simple script to open a file in a popup window by clicking on a button. This used to work, but with all the jQuery updates (even with the migration file), this no longer works.

I found this, but this opens the popup and also redirects to the file url:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.popup').click(function(event) {
    window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
 });
});
```

Any way to get a simple popup? It needs to have scrollbars, preferably resizable. I've seen lots of posts for modal boxes, but that does not accomplish what I need. The popup box has it's own design and there is more content than would be suitable for a modal.

I also want to avoid adding any extra markup. It makes the most sense to just add a class, like the example above.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('.popup').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
});
```

You have to include jQuery reference to work this,
here is the working sampe
http://jsfiddle.net/a7qJt/

Comment: @jenhan: see the sample shared

Comment: Thanks Chamika. I do have jQuery referenced. I think it's an IE issue. It's working in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Button click event only.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnext").click(function () {                    
                    window.open("HTMLPage.htm", "PopupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no");
                });
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `return false;` in your click callback like this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.popup').click(function(event) {
      window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
      return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: @jenhan Do you have popups blocked by any chance?

Comment: No, I had checked that and they're not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.popup').click(function(event) {
    window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/open-link-in-new-tab-or-new-popup.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('A.BLAH').click(function() {
var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'height=600,width=1000');
if (window.focus)
{
NWin.focus();
}
return false;
});
});
```