# How to render server response as HTML into a popup window? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, response

so I'm getting an email's HTML response back from the server and in jQuery I'm trying to render that response into a popup window.

I tried this at first:

```
postToServerWithAjax('/invite_preview', null, function (response) {
    window.open($(response), "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
});
```

However that just opened up the Popup window with [object, object] in the URL. I tried .html() below

```
postToServerWithAjax('/invite_preview', null, function (response) {
    window.open($(response).html(), "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
});
```

^ And this just returned a blank popup window

I then tried just a blank page, but my code keeps placing the HTML into the url bar:

```
window.open(response).html();
```

[image]

What am I missing to actually render the HTML into the new popup/page?

Found some examples here, and used the answers, but haven't gotten the HTML to render yet :(

[display html code of response returned by ajax, Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900875/display-html-code-of-response-returned-by-ajax-jquery)

[jQuery function to open link in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570149/jquery-function-to-open-link-in-new-window)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first parameter is a URL, not actual content, you have to write that to the window

```
postToServerWithAjax('/invite_preview', null, function (response) {
   var wind = window.open("", "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
   wind.document.write(response);
});
```